# multiple api request using retrofit and rx java

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2, rx-android

I am new to android and I have a scenario where I want to get get data from multiple api. Let suppose **api_a**, **api_b**, **api_c**, **api_d**. These api are independent of each other but I want to show data from these api in a mix Recycler View (**horizontal and vertical**). So I want to make these api call in such a manner so that I can get every api data at a time so that i can display in recycler view.
I already using **retrofit 2** but for that I had to chain them one by one which is very lengthy and I think this is not a feasible approach. I know little bit about **RX JAVA** ,but I only know how to make one request at a time. Please help

Comment: Try the accepted answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401193/multiple-requests-with-retrofit-to-combine-results

Comment: suppose the result of these 4 api gives me 4 different string which are independent of each other can i get that?

Comment: check it out https://github.com/fakefacebook/Retrofit-2-with-Rxjava-multiple-request

Answer (score 24):

There are at least 2 ways to achieve this -

**1) Using RxJava Zip operator** (for parallel requests)

Get all the observables

```
Observable<ResponseType1> observable1 = retrofit.getApi_a();
Observable<ResponseType2> observable2 = retrofit.getApi_b();
Observable<ResponseType3> observable3 = retrofit.getApi_c();
```

Zip the observables to get a final observable

```
Observable<List<String>> result = 
Observable.zip(observable1.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), observable2.subscribeOn(Schedulers
            .io()), observable3.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), new Function3<ResponseType1, ResponseType2, ResponseType3, List<String>>() {
    @Override
    public List<String> apply(ResponseType1 type1, ResponseType2 type2, ResponseType3 type3) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(type1.data);
        list.add(type2.data);
        list.add(type3.data);
        return list;
    }
});
```

now subscribe on the resultant observable

```
result.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new Observer<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<String> s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "s is the list with all the data");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

**2) Using RxJava flatMap() operator.** (To request serially one after another)

This is simple chaining of requests

```
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Disposable disposable = retrofit.getApi_a()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap((Function<ResponseType1, ObservableSource<ResponseType2>>) response1 -> {
                result.add(response1.data);
                return retrofit.getApi_b();
            })
            .flatMap((Function<ResponseType2, ObservableSource<ResponseType3>>) response2 -> {
                result.add(response2.data);
                return retrofit.getApi_c();
            })
            .map(response3 -> {
                result.add(response3.data);
                return response3;
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Response3>() {

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response3 response3) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "result variable will have all the data");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Comment: What happend if any one api fails in Zip or Flatmap ?

Answer (score 0):

For combining multiple Observables you may want to consider the **Merge** operator.
This would allow you to combine the stream of multiple requests into a single Observable.

Merge will interleave them as they are emitted. If sequence matters, there is also **Concat** which will emit from each Observable before continuing with the next.

**Rx Doc**

- Merge: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html
- Concat: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html

Comment: actually my requirement is not to merge them but to get separate data but i want the to execute parallel and not one by one

Comment: I see, using Observables with Retrofit your requests will be asynchronous. You can fire off each API request and handle the responses with OnNext as they return.

Comment: can you show give me some link which retrofit and rx java is used for multiple api call

Comment: What is I have more than 4 requests to combine? Merge accepts only 4

Answer (score 0):

Merge operator combines multiple observable into one

Set up Base URL of API:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .client(oktHttpClient.build())
                    .build();
```

Now setup two observables for the two network requests:

```
Observable<JsonElement> Observable1 = ApiClient.getApiService().getApi_1();

Observable<JsonElement> Observable2 = ApiClient.getApiService().getApi_2();
```

Now we use RxJava's mergemethod to combine our two Observables:

```
Observable.merge(Observable1, Observable2 )
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<JsonElement>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(JsonElement value) {
                        Log.d("RESPONSE", "onNext:=======" + value);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        Log.d("RESPONSE", "DONE==========");
                    }
                });
```