# Is it possible , multiple rest API hit within single network request by retrofit network library

Tags: android, retrofit

I am beginner in android .I have three rest API . I want to hit three rest API within single network request.is it possible ???. 
if possible give me some resource .
thank you

Comment: In general 3 API call means 3 network call but I get what you are asing. Either You can merge all the 3 in one or find a possibility of batch. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474120/how-to-make-multiple-request-and-wait-until-data-is-come-from-all-the-requests-i

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51112602/multiple-api-request-using-retrofit-and-rx-java

Comment: except rx java , have any mechanism in retrofit for handle this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not hit more than one API in a single request. You have to create multiple request.You can follow this link for more information about retrofit :- https://square.github.io/retrofit/