# How to make retrofit calls single threaded in android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

i am currently working on a project with retrofit, i have multiple WS calls and in order to use them i use the following code:

```
      call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(...
```

In some views i have multiple calls up to 5 or 6 and this was working fine , but when i advanced i nnoticed that i need to make the calls simultaneous so they can go one after the other .

Is there a way to make retrofit calls synchronized so they can go one after the other ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, It seems you need chaining of you API calls to a single task rather than repetitive calling. Here, you can find something

[RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846677/combining-api-calls-with-rx-java)

[Chaining of API Calls](https://medium.com/@adinugroho/chaining-multiple-retrofit-call-using-rxjava-177b64c8103e)

Hope it helps

Comment: Personally, I'd like to suggest RxJava for combining requests. It's a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it synchronious by NOT adding a callback method.

For example:

```
service.getTasks().execute();
```

Comment: can you detail your answer ? i am farahead in my project (8 months of coding ) so replacing all the calls is not that simple, when and where execute the 
 `service.getTasks().execute(); `

Answer (score 1):

For synchronous requests with retrofit :

```
Call<List<Task>> call = retrofitService.getData(); 
List<Data>> data = call.execute().body();
```

You need to do this in the background thread though.